# Finding Percentages

Tags: java, numbers

I am currently trying to find odd and even numbers and how many of the odd and even numbers and also the percentage of odd and even numbers. Now every time i try to input this it says percentage zero can you tell me why.

```
    int one = 0;
    int two = 0;
    int three = 0;
    int four = 0;
    int five = 0;

    String oneString="";
    String twoString="";
    String threeString="";
    String fourString="";
    String fiveString="";

    int evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0, zeroCount = 0;

    oneString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your first number");
    one = Integer.parseInt (oneString);
    while (one > 0) {
        one = one % 10;
        if (one%2==0) {
            evenCount++;
        }
        else{ 
            oddCount++;
        }
        one = one / 10;
    }
    twoString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your second number");
    two = Integer.parseInt (twoString);

    while (two > 0) {
        two = two % 10;
        if (two%2==0){
            evenCount++;
        }else { 
            oddCount++;
        }
        two = two / 10;
    }
    threeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your third number");
    three = Integer.parseInt (threeString);

    while (three > 0) {
        three = three % 10;
        if (three%2==0){
           evenCount++;
        }else{ 
           oddCount++;
        }
    three = three / 10;
    }
    fourString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your fourth number");
    four = Integer.parseInt (fourString);
    while (four > 0) {
        four = four % 10;
        if (four%2==0){
        evenCount++;
        }else{ 
           oddCount++;
        }
        four = four / 10;
    }
    fiveString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Input your fifth number");
    five = Integer.parseInt (fiveString);
    while (five > 0) {
        five = five % 10;
        if (five%2==0){
           evenCount++;
        }else{ 
           oddCount++;
        }
        five = five / 10;
   }
   int count = 0;
   count = evenCount + oddCount;

   System.out.println(); 
   System.out.printf("Even: %d Odd: %d",evenCount, oddCount);

   int percentage = 0;
   percentage = evenCount / count;
   percentage = percentage * 100;
   System.out.println(" Percentage  of Even " + percentage);

   int oddpercentage = 0;
   oddpercentage = oddCount / count;
   oddpercentage = oddpercentage * 100;
   System.out.println(" Percentage  of Odd " + oddpercentage);
```

Comment: Why are you not using loops?

Answer (score 2):

You got `0` because you declare your percentage and oddpercentage variables as `int` datatype. change them to `double` datatype. The *divider* number should be `double` as well.

This is because, any integer number that divided by a larger integer number will give you `0`. for example, `1/2 = 0`, `2/5 = 0`, `99/100 = 0`

Then, instead of doing like this,

```
percentage = oddCount / count;
percentage = oddpercentage * 100;
```

You can simply do like this:

```
percentage = oddCount * 100 / (double) count;
```

**Note:**

You **don't** have to do `one = one % 10;` to check for odd/even number

This is enough:

```
if (one %2==0) {
   evenCount++;
}
else { 
   oddCount++;
}
```

And **remove** your `while` loop, it doesn't necessary or no use at all

Comment: ok thanks i did that but now the count says even 1 odd 6 when i put in all odds. why is that the only thing i changed was what you said

Comment: @user3183992 I don't get what are you trying to say

Comment: i input 5 even numbers and the count becomes 6 evens and 1 odd

Comment: @user3183992 check the updated answer. remove the `one = one % 10, two= two% 10 ` and so on, and remove your `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

You defined percentage as an int.

This means you are doing (as an example)

int percentage = (int)43/100 = (int)0.43 = 0

Multiplying this by 100 gives you 0*100 = 0.

Try using a double and then multiplying by 100 to see if you get somewhere.
If you particularly want to have only an integer you can work from the double you are left with (which will contain decimal places) and do the integer value of that.

Comment: ok thanks i did that but now the count says even 1 odd 6 when i put in all odds. why is that the only thing i changed was what you said

Answer (score 0):

you're getting 1 even odd 6 because you have to change both percentage and oddpercentage to double (and not only percentage), just like this

public class X {

```
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int one = 0;
            int two = 0;
            int three = 0;
            int four = 0;
            int five = 0;

            String oneString="";
            String twoString="";
            String threeString="";
            String fourString="";
            String fiveString="";

            int evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0, zeroCount = 0;

            oneString = "1";
            one = Integer.parseInt (oneString);
            while (one > 0) {
                one = one % 10;
                if (one%2==0) {
                    evenCount++;
                }
                else{ 
                    oddCount++;
                }
                one = one / 10;
            }
            twoString = "1";
            two = Integer.parseInt (twoString);

            while (two > 0) {
                two = two % 10;
                if (two%2==0){
                    evenCount++;
                }else { 
                    oddCount++;
                }
                two = two / 10;
            }
            threeString = "2";
            three = Integer.parseInt (threeString);

            while (three > 0) {
                three = three % 10;
                if (three%2==0){
                   evenCount++;
                }else{ 
                   oddCount++;
                }
            three = three / 10;
            }
            fourString = "3";
            four = Integer.parseInt (fourString);
            while (four > 0) {
                four = four % 10;
                if (four%2==0){
                evenCount++;
                }else{ 
                   oddCount++;
                }
                four = four / 10;
            }
            fiveString = "5";
            five = Integer.parseInt (fiveString);
            while (five > 0) {
                five = five % 10;
                if (five%2==0){
                   evenCount++;
                }else{ 
                   oddCount++;
                }
                five = five / 10;
           }
           int count = 0;
           count = evenCount + oddCount;

           System.out.println(); 
           System.out.printf("Even: %d Odd: %d",evenCount, oddCount);

           double percentage = 0; ///// HERE
           percentage = evenCount / count;
           percentage = percentage * 100;
           System.out.println(" Percentage  of Even " + percentage);

           double oddpercentage = 0; ///// AND HERE
           oddpercentage = oddCount / count;
           oddpercentage = oddpercentage * 100;
           System.out.println(" Percentage  of Odd " + oddpercentage);

    }
```